# Consistent, Complete, and Recursive axiomitization of Arithmetic that does not include Q?

Tags: logic

I *think* I understand Godel's Incompleteness Theorem to say that there is no set of axioms $A$ based on the language of arithmetic ($0, s, +, *$) that has all of the following properties:

1. It is consistent:  We don't have $A \vdash \phi$ and $A \vdash \neg \phi$ for some $\phi$
2. It is complete: for every first-order logic sentence $\phi$ that we can formulate using the language of arithmetic, we have either $A \vdash \phi$ or $A \vdash \neg \phi$
3. It is recursive: Effectively, a computer program can decide whether some give statement is one of the axioms of $A$ or not
4. It is 'strong enough': The axioms imply various statements that, under the standard interpretation, express truths about such things as statements being one of the axioms and, most crucially, statements being derivable-from-the-axioms. I know that any set of axioms that includes (or is able to derive) PA or Q/Robinson would fit the bill.

This got me thinking: 4 seems to be requiring that the axioms express (under the standard interpretation) certain elementary truths about arithmetic, since from those axioms we then need to be able to infer further statements that (under the standard interpretation) express further truths about statements being derivable, which in turn will then show that some statements (e.g. the 'Godel statement' for that set of axioms) are in fact not derivable.

But what if we drop this requirement? What if the axioms are simply a bunch of statements that, while using the language of arithmetic, do not express arithmetical truths? So statements like $\forall x \ x+x = x$ or $s(0) + s(0) = s(s(s(0)))$? Obviously, it is not clear what good such an axiom system would do if they don't capture things that we normally consider 'true' in the world of arithmetic, but still: maybe we can consistently, completely, and recursively capture some world, even if that is not the world of arithmetic involving natural numbers, addition, and multiplication that we have in mind? That is: can we have a set of axioms that satisfy 1, 2, and 3, by dropping 4?

Put differently:   We *want* of course a set of axioms that capture elementary truths about arithmetic, so that our theorems *are* about a domain that is meaningful to us and that has important applications to the real world. This is why we have the kinds of axioms in systems like PA or Q that we do. But I was wondering if there was something to the interplay of the expressive power of language (meant purely syntactically), consistency, completeness, and recursion that *already* would rule out having any set of axioms expressed in a language with certain expressive power satisfy just properties 1, 2, and 3? So maybe put differently yet: Is Godel's Incompleteness result a result about pure formalism that merely says something about manipulations of strings of symbols, without getting any semantics or truth at all?

My thoughts:  Without constraint 4, the axioms no longer need to express elementary truths about arithmetic. So, consider that we use our standard interpretation for $0$, $s$, and $+$, but interpret $*$ to be addition as well. As such, we could take the axioms for Presburger Arithmetic, and simply add a couple of axioms for $*$ that mirror those for $+$, e.g. we would have $\forall x \ x*0 = 0$ and $\forall x \forall y \ x * s(y) = s(x * y)$.

So with these axioms, and with this interpretation, we have effectively obtained (a somewhat redundantly expressed version of) Presburger Arithmetic. And I believe Presburger arithmetic has properties 1,2, and 3. So that means the answer to my question is that we can satisfy 1, 2, and 3 if we drop 4?

And, extending this kind of thinking: it seems we can interpret any of the symbols (constants, predicates, functions) of any language in a way to make it compatible with Presburger Arithmetic, and so given *any* language there is a complete, consistent, and recursive set of axioms? That is, the *potential* expressive power of a language isn't so much the 'problem' that leads to Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, but it is really the insistence that a certain minimal set of statements be included in the axioms?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... Yes, [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) is **not** "strong enough" because it lacks multiplication (but has Induction; in Robinson we have multiplication but induction is lacking. Thus, there is a subtle interplay between "expressive capabilities"). The "strong enough" requirement is needed in order to *represent* (in the technical sense) primitive recursive functions: without multiplication we cannot do it. Maybe here is the key-point hiding...

Comment: You can add a mult symbol without the "desired" properties: you can add the symbol without specific axioms. Thus, what we have are only the "logical" axioms corresponding to it, e.g. $x ∗ y=x ∗ y$ and so on.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am troubled that you don't understand my question ... that strongly suggests to me that I myself still don't understand this material good enough to ask a clear question. My core questions is:  If you take the typical language of arithmetic, which includes constant symbol $0$, a 1-place function symbol $s$, and two 2-place symbols $+$ and $*$, can you come up with a set of axioms that is complete, consistent, and recursive? If this question is not clear, could you indicate where and why and how it is not clear? I thought I was pretty ok with these concepts, but maybe not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to bring Presburger arithmetic into the picture. Every language has a decidable structure (= a structure in that language whose - a priori complete and consistent - first-order theory is recursive): consider, given an arbitrary language $\Sigma$, the unique $\Sigma$-structure with a single element in which all relation symbols in $\Sigma$ get interpreted as the empty relation.

More generally, given any languages $\Sigma_0\subseteq\Sigma_1$ and any $\Sigma_0$-structure $\mathcal{M}$, consider the $\Sigma_1$-structure $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$ gotten by expanding $\mathcal{M}$ by interpreting all function symbols in $\Sigma_1\setminus \Sigma_0$ as projection onto the first coordinate and interpreting all relation symbols in $\Sigma_1\setminus\Sigma_0$ as the empty relation in the appropriate arity *(fine, things get a bit less natural if $\Sigma_1\setminus\Sigma_0$ has constant symbols, but meh)*. Then $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$ is no more complicated than $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Ah yes, I was just thinking about doing something along those lines: making it all just trivial.... so it seems like my thinking is on the right track then? We *can* (trivially) have 1,2, and 3, but we *can't* have 1,2,3, *and* 4?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes. In fact, any three of the four can be achieved. (Although FWIW I'd express 4 more formally via **interpretability** - "strong enough" should mean "interprets $\mathsf{Q}$.")

Comment: Ah, good to know. Thanks as always Noah!!